# Android Java static identifier or type expected

Tags: java, android, arrays, types, identifier

I got following lines of code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < articles.length(); i++) {
  static {
    addItem(new JsonParserItem("1", R.drawable.p1, "asd", "Steve Jobs", "Focusing is about saying No."));
  }
}
```

After static I get a red marker (error) which tells me

> identifier or type expected

how can I solve this

Comment: Don't try to wrap the functionality in a static block (whatever that's intended to be)?

Comment: @DaveNewton So I just do not use the static block

Comment: why you use static block? because it looks cool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you have a static block in there? 
That's supposed to be under a class, not inside a for loop.

Remove that and your syntax error should disappear:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < articles.length(); i++) {
       addItem(new JsonParserItem("1", R.drawable.p1, "asd", "Steve Jobs", "Focusing is about saying No."));
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Static should not be inside a method. See the following question for more information on how to use Static in Java : [What does the 'static' keyword do in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-a-class).